# Cannot Access Virtual Host Via Apache On Localhost

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, proxy, redhat, virtualhost

I'm beginning to pull out my hair.

Using Redhat/Apache we've three virtual hosts set up to serve three Drupal based domains and a fourth virtual host set up to serve Redmine via passenger all from one machine.

This set up is fine for all traffic, all network addresses can resolve all four domains. Due to the networking infrastructure, the box in question uses a proxy to see the outside world.

I have attempted to access the Redmine API from a script on the local machine and the response is an error:

```
While trying to retrieve the URL: http://projects/users.xml 

The following error was encountered: 

Unable to determine IP address from host name for projects 
The dnsserver returned: 

Name Error: The domain name does not exist. 
This means that: 

 The cache was not able to resolve the hostname presented in the URL. 
 Check if the address is correct.
```

Accessing the API from an external machine provides the expected response, so the API  is accessible - which leads me to believe that this is only a problem with Apache or/and PHP resolving the virtual host domain from itself.

I've made an educated guess that this might be a proxy issue, that the proxy being used is unaware of the local network DNS, but I don't know how to turn the proxy off for Apache to check, as I didn't set up this server and not familiar with proxy requirements generally.

If I can confirm whether or not this is a proxy issue, how do I make an exception for certain domains? I assume I need to make use of the NO_PROXY environment variable, but again, I don't know how to do this for the Apache user, and more importantly, dumping the ENV variables for the Apache user doesn't show a HTTP_PROXY value at all, so I am assuming Apache uses proxy configuration elsewhere.

Am I missing something obvious?

**EDIT:**
As requested, nslookup for the domain returns:

```
$ nslookup projects
Server:         10.11.6.31
Address:        10.11.6.31#53

Name:   projects.INNSERVE.LOCAL
Address: 10.11.6.48
```

**EDIT 2:**
As requested, wget results for URL in question:

```
$ wget projects/users.xml
--2012-12-22 19:12:51--  http://projects/users.xml
Resolving projects... 10.11.6.48
Connecting to projects|10.11.6.48|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Authorization Required
Authorization failed.
```

Comment: Show us result of "nslookup project" from local machine.

Comment: I've added the `nslookup` results to question. @alterpub

Comment: Could you please post the output of wget http://projects/users.xml

Comment: I've added `wget` results to question. @EricDANNIELOU

Comment: what do you get by accesing the ip directly?

Comment: wget seems to work fine except that it seems a login/password (or anything else is needed to access http://projects/users.xml : Therefore I suspect the problem comes from script on the local machine (or it does not give the good error message

Comment: @w0rldart can't access the IP directly in this instance as redmine is served from a virtual host - the ip directly is set to return a drupal installation served by the servers main hostname.

Comment: @EricDANNIELOU yeah, that's correct - the redmine API requires a login and this script runs fine from a different machine - it's simply when the script is run from the same machine as the virtual host, it seems unable to resolve the virtual host served by itself.

Comment: Without information about the script, the problem will be hard to troubleshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of desperation we've managed to fix the problem by re-defining the Apache webserver hosts files. Previously we had used Webmin to set these up (mostly, I created the projects hosts entry by hand for serving the Redmine installation via passenger).

The issue was as follows:

Projects was defined as a virtual host with a port number:

```
<VirtualHost our.ip.address:80>
DocumentRoot /opt/redmine-2.1.2/public
ServerName projects
...
```

Whilst all other virtual hosts were defined without explicitly labelling the port number:

```
<VirtualHost our.ip.address>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerName address.domain.local
    ServerAlias address
```

This worked fine in every respect other than Apache resolving it's own virtual hosts.

Changing the remaining virtual hosts to include the port number appears to have corrected this (and port numbers are important as we use multiple port numbers for various reasons not pertinent here).

Answer (score 2):

I'd try one of the following :

add

```
domain example.com
search example.com
```

to /etc/resolv.conf

Or add

```
11.22.33.44    projects.example.com projects
```

to /etc/hosts

Any of these are likely to solve the dns issue.

Comment: Hi Eric, all virtual hosts are already mapped in etc/hosts, domain is already defined, adding a search record to match makes no difference even after apache restart.